# Where to place my error boundary when data is provided by a context provider?

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, react-error-boundary

I am trying to build a react application. In order to handle errors I am using react-error-boundary.

I am receiving a list of names from the server. I have enclosed the components inside `Listprovider` to pass value of `list` to every child. Here is the code:

```
export default function App() {
  const {list}= useList();     //extract data provided by ListProvider
  const isFetching= useIsFetching('List');    //react-query

  const nameArr=list.map(el=>{
    return <div>{el.name}</div>
  })

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <>
        <h2>Hello World</h2>
        <h4>Jsonplaceholder user name</h4>
      </>
      <ErrorBoundary FallbackComponent={ErrorFallback}>

      {
        isFetching? 
        <div>Loading... </div>
        :
        <>
          {nameArr}
        </>
      }
      </ErrorBoundary>

    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried to enclose the mapped list with my error boundary. But when an error occurs instead of falling to my fallback component I see a blank page appear.

I have reproduced my query. One can visit here: https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-flower-f99c0e?file=/src/App.js.
For reproducing the error on can change the URL in `Functions/axiosFunctions.js`

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

[See the docs for handling async errors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-error-boundary#:%7E:text=the%20resetKeys.-,useErrorHandler,-(error%3F%3A%20unknown)). Error boundaries by default won't handle errors thrown in async code, like network activity. It will only handle synchronous render issues during the component lifecycle.

The error boundary library does have an escape hatch as documented though.

Comment: I have specified `useErrorBoundary` to true in the `useQuery` function so that the error is handled by the nearest error boundary.